# How to hide a column in KoGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, kogrid

I have started working with koGrid. And I want to hide a special column 'id' in koGrid.How can i do that?

```
 gridOptions : {
        displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
        data: items,
        multiSelect: false, 
        enableColumnResize: true,                
        columnDefs: [
                      { field: 'id', displayName: 'id' },
                      { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' }

        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`visible` option on the `columnDefs`](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/Defining-Columns) what you can set to `false`:

```
columnDefs: [
    { field: 'id', displayName: 'id', visible: false },
    { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' }
]
```

Or if you don't need the `id` value anywhere (so you're not using in template, or filtering sorting, etc.) you can just leave out the whole `{ field: 'id', displayName: 'id' }`.